# Vectors in Fields of the form $F^n_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I can't understand the concept of vectors in the field $F^n_p$

How many vectors should be there? What should be their elements?

For example, if we have a vector space $F^3_2$,

{(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)} Could this be a subspace of $F^3_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field $F_p$ has $p$ elements and the vector space $F_p^n$ is as a set

$$ \{ (x_1, \dots, x_n) : x_i\in F_p \}.$$

For every coordinate you have to choose an element of $F_p$. Hence, you have for every coordinate $p$ possible choices. This means your vector space consists of $p^n$ elements.

The set you wrote down is in fact not a subspace. For this it would need to contain

$$ (1,1,0)=(1,0,0)+(0,1,0) $$

which it doesn't.